# Build nginx with Lua on RPM system

Tags: nginx, lua, rpm

I want to build nginx with Lua third party module. This module requires Lua library. Lua 5.1 is installed on my server. But when I run ./compile with the the path to the nginx lua module. An error is thrown:

```
checking for Lua library ... not found 
checking for Lua library in /usr/local/ ... not found 
checking for Lua library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found 
checking for Lua library in /opt/local/ ... not found 
checking for Lua library in /usr/local/../lua51/ ... not found 
checking for Lua library in /usr/ ... not found  
./configure: error: ngx_http_lua_module requires the Lua library.
```

I tried giving path by export `LUA_LIB=/usr/local/lib/` but that also did not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you'll need package `lua-devel`.

Comment: that worked like a charm, also I solved other dependencies by installing DEVELOPER packages for each dependency.

Comment: The following worked for me: `sudo apt-get install libluajit-5.1-dev`